# How to swap 2 imputed charters from an imputed string?

Tags: java

How do I create a program that will input a sentence, and then two letters, and then switch all instances of those letters, then print out the switched sentence. For instance, if the person inputs “I like to eat bananas” and then “e” and “a,” your program would print “I lika to aet benenes".

So far I have this code but I am stuck and don't know much about converting to array or string builder. I know it is incompatible types but I just want to show that I am trying and this is my idea so far based on research.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringLetterSwitcher
{
public static void main(String [] arga)
{
   System.out.println("Enter your string");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   String originalString = scan.nextLine();

   System.out.println("What 2 letters would you like to swap?");
   String letter1 = scan.nextLine();
   String letter2 = scan.nextLine();

     char[] c = originalString.toCharArray();

     char temp = c[letter1];
     c[letter1] = c[letter2];
     c[letter2] = temp;

    String swappedString = new String(c);
    System.out.println(swappedString);
}
```

}

Comment: Please try something, arrays or stringbuilder should be able to do it. As is, your post looks like a straight dump of the assignment.

Comment: I am not looking for an exact answer. I have researched but I don't understand arrays or string builder or how to even implement them without straight up copying someones work.

Comment: Then first dedicate some time training with arrays until you're comfortable with them. With this experience duly worked on, StringBuilders will become easy to understand if you prefer that instead. You will then become able to solve this problem trivially.

Comment: I am trying to but I am barley understanding it and I am just hoping if someone can help me with this and shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

I used String.replace() to replace letter1 with letter2, then found the indexes of letter2 in the originalString to replace letter2 with letter1 (Notice that char[] c is newString, not originalString).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter your string");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String originalString = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What 2 letters would you like to swap?");
    String letter1 = scan.nextLine();
    String letter2 = scan.nextLine();

    String newString = originalString.replace(letter1, letter2);        //replaced letter1 with letter2
    char[] c = newString.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<originalString.length(); i++) {
        if (originalString.charAt(i) == letter2.charAt(0)) {            //if char in originalString == letter2
            c[i] = letter1.charAt(0);                                   //replaced letter2 with letter1
        }       
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```